# Error: Ziggy error: 'id' parameter is required for route

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I am working on single SPA using laravel and inertia js. I am using multi language as well. So I am passing language as prefix parameter like this.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{language}'],function(){
    Route::get('events',[HomeController::class,'event'])->name('events');
    Route::get('events-details/{id}',[HomeController::class,'eventDetail'])
           ->name('events.reservations.index');  
});
```

my controller

```
public function eventDetail($land,$id)
    {
        $events = $this->repository->getAllEvents();
        $event_details = $this->repository->findById($id);
        $time_interval = ReservationHelper::getTimeInterval();
        return Inertia::render('Frontend/Pages/Reservation/Index', compact('events','event_details','time_interval'));
    }
```

Calling in vue component like this

```
 <Link
      :href="
        route('events.reservations.index', [$page.props.current_locale, id])
      "
    >
      <div class="sao-box1 text-center">
        <img :src="imgSrc" alt="" class="img-fluid rounded_img" />
        <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
        <div class="event-description" v-html="description"></div>
        <a class="sl-btnBook">Book</a>
      </div>
    </Link>
```

when I click on that link I am getting error as

```
Error: Ziggy error: 'id' parameter is required for route 'events.reservations.index'
```

I don't know where I am going wrong.

thank you

Comment: What is the id on vuejs component? try debugging that with vue dev tools

Comment: ID is there. I can able to see but when I am  clicking on that I am getting this error

Comment: if you run php artisan route:list, how does the url in question look like from that output?

Comment: its coming like this  {language}/events-details/{id}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change this line only from :-

`:href="route('events.reservations.index', [$page.props.current_locale, id])"`

to :

`:href="route('events.reservations.index', {language : $page.props.current_locale, id: id})"`

thanks

Answer (score 0):

in your home controller event class. Check to see if you included "id" in the select in the query.

```
Eg., select('*') or select('id','eventname','eventdate')
```